# Firefox thinks I'm using and older Flash version

Tags: linux, firefox, flash, flash-player, fedora-20

I'm running Firefox 35.0 on Fedora 20. It has the current latest Adobe Flash version (11.2.202.440).

Firefox is blocking Flash and displaying an alert bar, claiming it is outdated:

[image]

In English: *Firefox has prevented an outdated plugin 'adobe flash' from running*

Just to be sure, I ran:

- `yum reinstall http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm` --  it installed `adobe-release-x86_64.noarch 0:1.0-1`.
- `yum reinstall flash-plugin` -- it installed `flash-plugin.x86_64 0:11.2.202.440-release`.

Then I restarted Firefox in safe mode and checked `about:plugins`.

```
Shockwave Flash

    File: libflashplayer.so
    Path: /usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
    Version: 11.2.202.425
    State: Enabled (STATE_VULNERABLE_UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
    Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
```

Checking the actual `.so` file for versions strings, it looks like I have the correct version.

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so | | grep "11.2.202"
FlashPlayer_11_2_202_440_FlashPlayer
LNX 11,2,202,440
11.2.202.440
drm/%s/%s/%s/11.2.202.440%s
```

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `pluginreg.dat` file on my Firefox profile folder:

```
Generated File. Do not edit.

[HEADER]
Version:0.17:$
Arch:x86_64-gcc3:$

[PLUGINS]
libflashplayer.so:$
/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so:$
11.2.202.425:$
```

(...)

Removing it forces Firefox to re-generate it with correct data.

Now `about:plugins` states:

```
Shockwave Flash

    Arquivo: libflashplayer.so
    Caminho: /usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
    Versão: 11.2.202.440
    Status: Ativo
    Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can disable the blocklist using `about:config`:

```
extensions.blocklist.enabled false
```

or using `prefs.js`:

```js
user_pref('extensions.blocklist.enabled', false);
```

- [blocklist.xml](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Blocklist.xml)
- [prefs.js](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/b175bb2/firefox/prefs.js#L107-L108)