# Is the official Adobe Flash repository for Linux outdated?

Tags: linux, firefox, flash, repository

## TL;DR version:

I am on Linux, manual downloads gives me v11.2.202.577, official repo gives me 11.2.202.569.

Is my copmuter brokened and how do I fix it?

---

I'm trying to update Flash for Linux using my OS's package manager, and it fails to provide me an up-to-date version (**up-to-date as in the 11.2 version tree**, I know Flash for Windows latest version is 21, I expected `dnf` to provide me with Flash 11.2.202.577)

If I visit the official download page, I can download [the binary for 11.2.202.577](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.577/flash-plugin-11.2.202.577-release.x86_64.rpm), **so Adobe is still offering 11.2 backports**. But the repo apparently is stuck at 11.2.202.569.

---

## Detailed version

Performing `dnf update --verbose` gets me:

```
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
Loaded plugins: migrate, noroot, debuginfo-install, Query, download, protected_packages, reposync, config-manager, builddep, system-upgrade, copr, playground, needs-restarting, generate_completion_cache
DNF version: 1.1.6

(... other repos ...)

repo: using cache for: adobe-linux-x86_64
not found deltainfo for: Adobe Systems Incorporated
not found updateinfo for: Adobe Systems Incorporated
repo: using cache for: rpmfusion-free
not found deltainfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 22 - Free
not found updateinfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 22 - Free

(... other repos ...)

repo: using cache for: updates
Russian Fedora for Fedora 22 - Free - Updates                                                                                 123 kB/s | 140 kB     00:01    

(...)

adobe-linux-x86_64: using metadata from Tue Mar  1 17:13:54 2016.
rpmfusion-free: using metadata from Wed Aug  5 09:49:43 2015.

(...)

updates: using metadata from Sun Apr  3 18:07:09 2016.

(...)

Last metadata expiration check performed 0:00:00 ago on Mon Apr  4 15:02:47 2016.
Completion plugin: Generating completion cache...
--> Starting dependency resolution
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.10.3-8.P3.fc22 will be upgraded
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.10.3-9.P4.fc22 will be an upgrade

(...)

---> Package chromium.x86_64 1:49.0.2623.108-1.fc22.R will be upgraded
---> Package chromium.x86_64 1:49.0.2623.110-1.fc22.R will be an upgrade
---> Package chromium-libffmpeg.x86_64 1:49.0.2623.108-1.fc22.R will be upgraded
---> Package chromium-libffmpeg.x86_64 1:49.0.2623.110-1.fc22.R will be an upgrade

(...)

--> Finished dependency resolution
Dependencies resolved.
```

Performing `dnf clean all` and then `dnf update` causes a lot of data fetching to occur, including from the adobe repo, but it still displays the same date (Mar  1 17):

```
(...)
Adobe Systems Incorporated                                                                                                    3.1 kB/s | 1.8 kB     00:00    
not found deltainfo for: Adobe Systems Incorporated
not found updateinfo for: Adobe Systems Incorporated
(...)
```

adobe-linux-x86_64: using metadata from Tue Mar  1 17:13:54 2016.

## Repository details

```
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/adobe-linux-x86_64.repo 
[adobe-linux-x86_64]
name=Adobe Systems Incorporated
baseurl=http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-adobe-linux
```

http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/ gives me 404

http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml is:

```
<repomd>
  <data type="other">
    <location href="repodata/other.xml.gz"/>
    <checksum type="sha">8a3454cf049cac24d0cec354d129ab89b4fdf5ce</checksum>
    <timestamp>1456863234</timestamp>
    <open-checksum type="sha">7745898d3eddf4692293413d8a29cb9e3ffcd843</open-checksum>
  </data>
   <data type="filelists">
        <location href="repodata/filelists.xml.gz" />
        <checksum type="sha">7b54b465547eb400102607b9d22922bb52d52705</checksum>
        <timestamp>1456863234</timestamp>
        <open-checksum type="sha">21eab3d4f0f8b03c642c71e544772e70957a5718</open-checksum>
    </data>
    <data type="primary">
      <location href="repodata/primary.xml.gz"/>
        <checksum type="sha">b42e0ca15e52334cd62d04fe95ffbc4547f13641</checksum>
          <timestamp>1456863234</timestamp>
          <open-checksum type="sha">3e36f0867eece5ee02a3040b78160ed271e9ee69</open-checksum>
    </data>
</repomd>
```

**Interestingly, 1456863234 Unix Time is Tue, 01 Mar 2016 20:13:54 GMT and 01 Mar 2016 17:13:54 BRT**

### Detailed details

I'm running Firefox on Fedora 23 and I've been getting the security alert for an outdated Flash version for quite a few days now:

[image]

If I open the `about:plugins` page, I get the following information 
(notice the part where it says **`(STATE_VULNERABLE_UPDATE_AVAILABLE)`**:

> Shockwave Flash
>
> ```
> Arquivo: libflashplayer.so
> Caminho: /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
> Versão: 11.2.202.569
> Status: Ativo (STATE_VULNERABLE_UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
> Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
> ```

Visiting the `about:addons` page also shows me a security alert:

[image]

Clicking the "Update now" link opens https://blocklist.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked/p1138, which states "Flash Player Plugin on Linux 11.2.202.559 to 11.2.202.569 (...) have been [blocked on March 18, 2016](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255519)" and has a link to the [Mozilla Plugin Check page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/).

That page also says I have Flash 11.2 r202 (11.2.202.569) and displays an "update" button linking to http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer.
[image]

The Adobe Flash Player download page says the latest version is 11.2.202.577. It correctly detects I'm on Linux 64-bit pt-br Firefox, and offers me a few download choices.

If I choose `.rpm`, it allows me to download [the binaries in an `.rpm` package](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.577/flash-plugin-11.2.202.577-release.x86_64.rpm). I do, howeber, prefer to use the package manager (in my case. `dnf` with a `yum` compatibility) to get my updates.

If I download the "[YUM package](http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm)" and `rpm -i` the file, it says I already have it installed. Removing `adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch` and then reinstalling the file produces the same result.

Comment: Adobe removed support for Linux version of flash about a year ago. Most users either switch to Chrome and use pepper flash, or switch to HTML 5

Comment: @Serg Ok, then how can I download [the binary for 11.2.202.577](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.577/flash-plugin-11.2.202.577-release.x86_64.rpm) but the repo apparently is stuck at 11.2.202.569?

Comment: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ for me shows the 577 version , perfectly fine tried that ?

Comment: @Serg it shows me the same, as stated in the question.

Comment: But then again you're installing an rmp package. I'm on Ubuntu, so I'll be getting `.deb` . There should be option for installing foreign package, try that maybe ?

Comment: Let me know if you want me to download the package and transfer it over to you over dropbox or something similar

Comment: What? No, I can download the package fine. I just don't want to use manual download methods, I prefer using the repositories. It's the Linux world after all, right? If I wanted manual downloads I'd have stayed on Windows! ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, turns out the repository is providing the correct version and it's a Firefox issue. One [I had already noticed more than a year ago](https://superuser.com/questions/873093/firefox-thinks-im-using-and-older-flash-version): Firefox incorrectly detects the Flash version based on the pluginreg.dat file on the Firefox profile folder.